When writing to .csv file in Python code, after some time I receive error: OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured
I have a code which periodically reads the values sent to the serial port from an Arduino and then writes them to a .csv . This code works on Windows, however, I am now switching from my windows laptop to a lab provided mac desktop with Sonoma OS. After some time (typically about 2 hours), the code stops with the same errors. I searched about this error and saw some other people having similar problems, however, I did not see a solution. Is there a clear cut way to fix this, or is it easier to see if I can get a Windows PC?
I have included the code for reference, as well as the errors.
Code:
import serial 
import csv
from   datetime import datetime
import time
from Syringe_Pump_Control import freq, step, Amp, a
from scipy.special import jv
import numpy as np

"""
Experimental Parameters:
These would need to be changed if a different solute is used or if two solutes
are being used.    
"""
Sc = 238 #Schmidt Number for HCl
D = 3.20E-5 #Diffusivity for HCl [=] cm^2/s
Qdiff = 6.32E-9 #From Harris and Goren [=] nol/hr

"""
Theoretical Flux Calculator:
Function is defined which calculates the theoretical flux based on the equations
in Harris and Goren
"""
def Flux(frequency, Sc):
    xi    = frequency*(a**2)*2*np.pi/(Sc*D*60)
    alpha = (-xi*complex(0,1))**(1/2)
    alpha_conj = np.conjugate(alpha)
    beta = (-xi*complex(0,1)*Sc)**(1/2)
    Num   = np.real((Sc**2)*((4*jv(0, beta)/(beta*jv(1, beta)))-((4*jv(0, alpha))/(alpha*jv(1, alpha)))))
    Den   = np.real(((Sc**2)-1)*((((4*jv(0, alpha))/(alpha*jv(1, alpha)))-(8/(alpha**2)))*((4*jv(0, alpha_conj)/(alpha_conj*jv(1, alpha_conj)))-(8/((alpha_conj)**2)))))
    RHS   = Num/Den
    Flux_theoretical = (RHS*(Amp**2)+1)*Qdiff
    return Flux_theoretical 
Flux_theoretical = np.round(Flux(freq, Sc), 11)

"""
Connect to Serial Port:
"""
arduino_port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem83301' #Connect to Arduino, this will be different on Mac
buad_rate = 9600      #Buad must match Arduino's
ser = serial.Serial(arduino_port, buad_rate)

"""
Create CSV file:
File should appear on the desktop as data.csv . The file will be read only since
this code is editing it.
"""
csv_file = open('data.csv', 'w', newline = '') 
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,escapechar='/')

"""
Write Parameters to CSV:
"""
csv_writer.writerow(['Polling Start Time & Date', datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), datetime.now().date()])
csv_writer.writerow(['Freq','Amp', 'Step', 'Theoretical Flux (mol/hr)'])
csv_writer.writerow([freq, Amp, step, Flux_theoretical])
csv_writer.writerow(['Time(min)','EC', 'pH'])


"""
Write Parameters to Terminal:
"""
print('Polling Start Time & Date', datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), datetime.now().date())
print('Freq =', freq,'Amp =', Amp, 'Step =', step, )
print('Theoretical Flux (mol/hr):', Flux_theoretical)
print('Time(min):','EC:', 'pH:')
"""
Begin polling time:
Time starts at 0 min when the code is ran and calculates the time in minutes 
between readings (approx. 1min.)
"""
start_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
"""
Read and write serial data to CSV:
"""
try:
    while True:
        # print('success')
        serial_data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        EC, pH = serial_data.split(',')
        print(round(((time.time() - start_time)/60),3), EC.replace('', ''), pH.replace('', ''))
        csv_writer.writerow([round(((time.time() - start_time)/60),3), EC.replace('', ''), pH.replace('', '')])
        csv_file.flush()
except KeyboardInterrupt():
        print( 'Interupted' )
"""
When the user wishes to view the data, open data.csv on the desktop and save 
as a csv file. The parameters and data can be copied into the template.
"""

Errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py:575 in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size - len(read))

OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/Desktop/Python_csv_Write.py:103
    serial_data = ser.readline().decode().strip()

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py:581 in read
    raise SerialException('read failed: {}'.format(e))

SerialException: read failed: [Errno 6] Device not configured


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Desktop/Python_csv_Write.py:108
    except KeyboardInterrupt():

TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

I thought this was happening due to the screen shutting off when polling data but leaving the screen on did not solve the issue. I am also running another python code which controls a syringe pump at the same time, and it does not have an issues running over a long time and has continued to run when this one stops. However, it does not write anything to files in the OS.

It's reading from the serial port, not writing to a CSV file, that this question relates to -- you might want to edit the title accordingly.

Beyond that -- have you inspected the system's logs? If the USB serial adapter is being reinitialized for some reason, for example, that might trigger it. Can other programs, besides your particular Python program, successfuly read from that device for an indefinite period of time on MacOS?

I will run this again and look at the system logs. I don't have another python program that does this. I can have the Arduino.ide open instead which displays the values to the serial monitor.

One thing you could try is recreating the ser object when this exception is thrown. Can't promise there won't be some data lost at the points where that takes place, but I wouldn't be surprised if that were happening unavoidably due to whatever underlying issue (whether that be OS-level, hardware-level or otherwise) is triggering the exception as it is.

I didn't realize this before but I get this same string of errors when I unplug the Arduino. Thank you for the help.
